# Return Value from Node Redis Command: Hubot and Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, redis, hubot

TL;DR **How can I get the return value out of the `client.ttl` callback for use outside of the `getTTL` function?**

Learning Coffeescript with Hubot and Redis, here. I've got a function that's not returning the value I expect it to.  The function here is designed to get the TTL for a Redis key and return the TTL value, e.g. 4000 (seconds).  Here's my Coffeescript:

```
getTTL = (key) ->
    client.ttl key, (err, reply) ->
        if err
            throw err
        else if reply in [-1, -2]
            "No TTL or key doesn't exist."
        else
            reply
    return
```

Now here is it compiled in JS:

```
var getTTL;

getTTL = function(key) {
  client.ttl(key, function(err, reply) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else if (reply === (-1) || reply === (-2)) {
      return "No TTL or key doesn't exist.";
    } else {
      return reply;
    }
  });
};
```

From [coffeescript return function callback acting strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471033/coffeescript-return-function-callback-acting-strange), I understand the need to add the empty `return`, but I'm still not receiving the value in the callback reply.  If I integrate the function with the [Response object](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/src/response.coffee) in Hubot, I can do `msg.send reply` and that works just fine to output the return value.

However, if I assign the return value of the function to a variable, e.g. `ttl_val = getTTL "some-key"`, then I only get a boolean value returned (`true`), which I'm assuming is the exit status of the `getTTL` function itself. So, my question is:

*What am I doing wrong that's preventing me from receiving the reply value in the callback function?* Do I need to do something like [How do I wait for a callback in coffeescript (or javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593424/how-do-i-wait-for-a-callback-in-coffeescript-or-javascript) to ensure that my callback completes before trying to yank the value?

Comment: I found a solution to my core problem using a different approach, but I'm still interested in this particular problem I was having...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup `getTTL` to accept its own callback function:

```
getTTL = (key, done = ()->) ->
    client.ttl key, (err, reply) ->
        if err
            throw err
        else if reply in [-1, -2]
            done "No TTL or key doesn't exist."
        else
            done reply
```

Then in your hubot script

```
robot.respond /what is the TTL for (.*)/i, (msg) ->
    getTTL msg.match[1] msg.send
```

**Edit**: To answer you're tl;dr edit: you cannot get the return value out of the callback. That value only exists in the context of the callback function. You can always assign that value to some kind of global variable from inside the callback function, but then you'll never know when that global value got assigned its value.

Comment: Sorry, let me know if the confusion was in my question.  I'm trying to store the value returned from `client.ttl`'s reply for use in another function, completely outside of the hubot response.  However, if I integrate the function with a `robot.respond` and do `msg.send`, it works just fine and outputs the TTL to console.  That's why I'm guessing the issue stems from my own (lack of) understanding regarding async callbacks...

Comment: @thankyour To answer you're tl;dr edit: you cannot get the return value out of the callback. That value only exists in the context of the callback function. You can always assign that value to some kind of global variable from inside the callback function, but then you'll never know when that global value got assigned its value.

Comment: dammit!  That's what I was afraid of...thanks for your time!  If you change your answer to reflect, I'll mark yours as correct...